# No se muestra el icono en una función con operador ternario

Tags: reactjs, operador-ternario

Como veis en la imagen creo que la lógica de la función es correcta, pero no se muestra como debería
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El icono aparece como se muestra usando las herramientas de desarrollador pero no lo veo visualmente alguna idea? Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Aparte... ¿Toogle o toggle?

Comment: No estas usando un operador ternario. Por lo menos en el código que agregaste como imagen (por favor agregalo como texto). Aqui hay mas información sobre operadores ternarios https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator Por favor agrega el resto de código de tu componente. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example]

Comment: Será que así no es la forma de cambiar el color al icono? porque en el pantallazo veo un icono rojo... y en tu código especificas o verde o gris (entonces puede que si se esté generando bien el tema del icono... pero el color no sea el correcto porque así no se le cambia el color)